# Drawing Straight line in react between two components

Tags: java, reactjs, mouseevent, draw

I want to draw a straight line between two components.The line should be either horizontal or vertical.The line should change its orientation from horizontal to vertical or vice versa while drawing from one component to the other.I have no idea how to achieve this.Please help me with the code or related material

Answer (score 0):

try this https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/tree/master.

This allows drawing a  line or any other drawing